# How to make a leaflet circleMarker draggable?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, leaflet

Using leaflet, I created a `L.circleMarker` and I want it to be draggable:

```
var marker = L.circleMarker(new L.LatLng(48.94603, 2.25912), {
    draggable: true
})
.bindPopup('Circle marker draggable')
.addTo(map)
.on('dragstart', onMarkerDragStart)
.on('dragend', onMarkerDragEnd);
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any call of `onMarkerDragStart/End` functions when I drag the marker. However, if we use `L.marker` instead of `L.circleMarker`, it works.

So, does anyone know how to make the `L.circleMarker` draggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the Leaflet.draw plugin to support circle markers. You can get it [here](https://github.com/pkeller3/Leaflet.draw)

I enable the drawing like this:

```
drawCircleMarker: function () {
            this.currentHandler = new L.Draw.CircleMarker(this.map, this.drawControl.options.circleMarker);
            this.currentHandler.enable();
        },
```

You will need to hook up to the map's draw:created event in order to get the layer that was added.

To enable dragging, simply take that layer that was added and enable editing on it like this:

```
pathToEdit.editing.enable();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the specification for [L.CircleMarker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker), [L.Circle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) and [L.Path](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) which it extends from, there is simply no drag for a CircleMarker. The option you now have is to use a custom [L.Icon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) for [L.Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker). Here is [an example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html) of custom icons taken from the Leaflet site.

Another option is to use this [polydrag](https://github.com/thatjpk/leaflet.polydrag) plugin, but it's developed against an early version of Leaflet (0.4.2) and isn't being maintained. You could always take a look at that source and roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Leaflet Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin and enable/disable editing on the circle marker.

```
circleMarker.editing.enable();
circleMarker.editing.disable();
```

If you're using TypeScript, you can use

```
circleMarker['editing'].enable();
circleMarker['editing'].disable();
```

This lets you edit the circle marker effectively letting you drag the circle marker around.

And for drag events, you can refer to draw events in [Leaflet.Draw.Event.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/develop/src/Leaflet.Draw.Event.js).

You can subscribe to `map` events like this:

```
map.on('draw:editmove', (event) => {
    // Do something
});
```

Or, directly subscribe to `circleMarker` events (`editstart`, `editdrag`, `edit`) like this:

```
circleMarker.on('editdrag', (event) => {
    // Do something
});
```