# Leaflet v1.03: Make CircleMarker draggable?

Tags: leaflet, draggable, move, geometry, marker

does some Leaflet guru has an idea, what's the easiest way to make a **CircleMarker** draggable in **Leaflet v1.0.3**?

It's easy to do it for "standard" markers by using the *"draggable"*-option. But such an option doesn't exist for CircleMarker. I tried it by using several Events, but the problem is, that not the marker is being moved but the underlying map.

Another possibility could be the use of *"stopPropagation"*-Function (but just for DOMEvents). Or the use of *"removeEventParent"*... if the "parent" of the CircleMarker is the map and its events?
Regarding to the Documentation there also *DOMUtility/Draggable*-class. Is this what I need?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Draggable Markers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
            html, body, #map {height: 100%;}
      </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
            var layerOsm = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicHBldGUiLCJhIjoiY2lsdmE2ZmQ2MDA4OHZxbTZpcmx1emtqbSJ9.Two7SPSaIZysqgOTrrLkRg', {
           subdomains: 'ab', maxZoom: 20, noWrap:true, attribution:'<a href="http://www.mapbox.com">Mapbox</a> | <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/">OpenStreetMap</a>' });
   var map = new L.Map('map').addLayer(layerOsm).setView(new L.LatLng(47.8, 13.0), 14);
            L.marker([47.8, 13.0], {draggable:true}).addTo(map);
            
            var circle = L.circleMarker([47.81, 13.01], {radius:30}).addTo(map);

            circle.on('mousedown', function () {
                map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
                    circle.setLatLng(e.latlng);
                });
            }); 
            map.on('mouseup', function(){
                map.removeEventListener('mousemove');
            })
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just googled this, as I'm, also trying to make the circleMarker draggable. I thought it would be an easy thing for a Friday afternoon, not so.

Comment: Not with `L.circleMarker`, but you can substitute [`L.divIcon()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#divicon) and make it look like a circle with css, and that *can* be made draggable.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226814/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a leaflet circleMarker draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061820/how-to-make-a-leaflet-circlemarker-draggable)

Answer (score 12):

Leaflet v1.0+ solution:

```js
var marker = L.circleMarker([41.91847, -74.62634]).addTo(map)

// extract trackCursor as a function so this specific
// "mousemove" listener can be removed on "mouseup" versus
// all listeners if we were to use map.off("mousemove")
function trackCursor(evt) {
  marker.setLatLng(evt.latlng)
}
    
marker.on("mousedown", function() {
  map.dragging.disable()
  map.on("mousemove", trackCursor)
})

map.on("mouseup", function() {
  map.dragging.enable()
  map.off("mousemove", trackCursor)
})
```

To make this behaviour more re-useable we could encapsulate it in a function (JS ES6 syntax):

```js
function moveableMarker(map, marker) {
  function trackCursor(evt) {
    marker.setLatLng(evt.latlng)
  }

  marker.on("mousedown", () => {
    map.dragging.disable()
    map.on("mousemove", trackCursor)
  })

  marker.on("mouseup", () => {
    map.dragging.enable()
    map.off("mousemove", trackCursor)
  })

  return marker
}
```

You can then make a marker draggable / moveable like so:

```js
const moveable = moveableMarker(map, marker)
```

These examples helped construct the above solution:

- [Akshay Agrawal's JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay_agrawal/76wwqrvh/)
- [Jedidiah Hurt's Leaflet 1.0 draggable circle](http://codepen.io/kad3nce/pen/bEdwOE)

Comment: Thanks Bill, your example from codepen.io is working, the other one from jsfiddle just with Leaflet 0.7, not with v1.0.3 (map is being moved instead of circle).

Still quite complicated to juggle with several events and to switch off/on map.dragging just to move a circleMarker.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Very good solution. One could adapt this solution as a feature of a subclass of Circle or any other object that has LatLng. I use it now to move a CircleMarker.

Comment: This is great, but if you happen to mouseup while hovering another marker then the event doesn't fire. It works better to register that handler on map instead of marker. E.g. `map.on("mouseup", ...`

Answer (score 1):

Found another answer at https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag/
I just added the Leaflet.Path.Drag.js. Now I can read in from my REST service all my sites and move them.

```
var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -73.7979125, 42.704642
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "popupContent": "This is Point 1. "
            },
            "id": 51
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -73.630371,42.698585
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "popupContent": "This is Point 2. "
            },
            "id": 52
        }
    ]
};

var map = L.map('map', {editable: true}).setView([43, -74], 8);

var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> //contributors'}).addTo(map);


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
var popupContent = feature.properties.popupContent
layer.bindPopup(popupContent);

    layer.on('dragend', function(e){
        console.log(layer.getLatLng().lat);
        console.log(layer.getLatLng().lng);
    });

}

var mymarker =L.geoJSON(data, {

style: function (feature) {
    return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
},

onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng,{ draggable: true }, {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    });
}
}).addTo(map);
```